# Vanilla Javascript algorithm, how to do it and explanation

Tags: javascript, closures

For my school assignment I have to code a pure Javascript function called:

```
foo(c)
```

that should return the following values:

```
foo('a')  // return 'fa'
foo()('b')  // return 'fob'
foo()()("t"))  // return 'foot'
```

So basically when the function is called with a character 'c' as parameter, the whole values are returned (note that calling foo() add a 'o' character in the overall returning value, and the first character returned of the final string is always 'f'.

Can someone provide a possible implementation? Ideally I would like to try on my own, so also hints and tips are most welcomed, as well as comments in the code.

NB: my greatest struggle at the moment is finding a way to chain the calling function.

Thank you.

Comment: *Ideally I would like to try on my own*, just start with some code here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive approach with arrow functions:

```
const foo = c => {
    let rec = acc => x => x === undefined ? rec(acc + "o") : foo(acc + x);
    return c === undefined ? rec("o") : "f" + c;
};

foo('t'); // "ft"
foo()('t'); // "fot"
foo()()('t'); // "foot"
```

`foo` is an unary function, but can handle the case, when it's called without any argument. The inner function `rec` is defined in curried form and accepts a accumulator as its first and a string as its second parameter. Whenever the second argument is omitted, `rec` recursively calls itself.

Comment: Beautiful approach... +

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo ( c ) {

  // Initialize the result
  var result = 'f';

  // Call the internal foo and return the result
  // Which will either be the function itself, or a string, depnding on 
  // whether or not a truthy argument was passed in
  return foo( c );

  function foo ( c ) {

      // If an argument was passed in, return the result
      if ( c )
          return result + c;

      // Otherwise append an 'o' to the result
      result += 'o';

      // and return the function so it can be called again
      return foo;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Iven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36741026/633183) inspired me to take on this fun challenge

```
// ES6
const foo = (x,y='f') => x && (y + x) || (x => foo(x, y + 'o'));
foo('a'); // "fa"
foo()('b'); // "fb"
foo()()('t'); // "foot"
```

---

For people still using ES5...

```
// ES5
var foo = function foo(x) {
  var y = arguments.length <= 1 || arguments[1] === undefined ? 'f' : arguments[1];
  return x && y + x || function (x) {
    return foo(x, y + 'o');
  };
};
foo('a'); // "fa"
foo()('b'); // "fb"
foo()()('t'); // "foot"
```

Comment: @NinaScholz it's ES6, so if you need it to work in an unsupported browser, just transpile it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not come up with brilliant ideas like @Iven Marquardt, a closure would do the job perfectly.

```
function Foo(){
  var count = 0,
        str = "";
  function f(a){
    if (!!a){
    str = "f"+"o".repeat(count)+a;
    count = 0;
    return str;
    }
  count++;
  return foo;
  }
  return f;
}
var foo = Foo();
foo('a')       // <- 'fa'
foo()('b')     // <- 'fob'
foo()()("t"))  // <- 'foot'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36770044/4543207), which shows a naive and conventional way of solving this problem, i wanted to add a separate answer all by itself since I didn't want this nice one to go unnoticed. The thing is, probably the most appropriate solution of this problem lies in a mostly overlooked specialty of the ES6 default values.

*When invoking a function if an argument with default value is not supplied then it's default value applies.* (it doesn't become "undefined")

Once you know this functionality the answer to this question is very straightforward and nothing more than a single liner.

```
var foo = (c, o = "") => !!c ? "f"+o+c : c => foo(c, o+= "o")
foo("a");    //fa
foo()("b");  //fob
foo()()("t") //foot
```